# How to go through ArrayList in VBScript

Tags: arraylist, vbscript

I have a VBScript in which I declare an `ArrayList` like this:

```
Dim MyOffices
Set MyOffices = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
```

and I fill them with my data from a database like this:

```
Do Until rs.EOF
    MyOffices.Add rs("codes")
    MyCount = MyCount +1
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

and then I want to show the values inside my `ArrayList` like this:

```
Dim i
For Each i In MyOffices
    response.write(i)
Next
```

but nothing gets written on the page. What could be the problem?

I know that there is data in the `ArrayList` because this code does show the text on the page:

```
Dim i
For Each i In MyOffices
    response.write("test")
Next
```

Comment: The code you posted should work. If nothing is displayed the problem is most likely with the data in the collection. What do you get when you output the item types (`response.write TypeName(i)`)?

Comment: With your code I will get Field for the datatype

Comment: Then try adding the field values: `MyOffices.Add rs("codes").Value`.